# Help with tomato pest problem

Tags: tomatoes, pests

first of all, thanks for taking time looking into my problem, it is greatly appreciated.

I need help identifying and combating a new pest on my tomato plants. I'm growing in a big city (Buenos Aires, Argentina). I took photos of the suspects and of the affected fruits, with cuts.

[image: On the plant with the suspect]
[image: Before cutting]
[image: Cuts in both directions]

EDIT (December 24th 2017):

More and new pictures by request:

This is how I noticed (this ones are new victims, but same simptoms), first it looked like this,then they looked like getting more red and afterwards it's like the first pictures.

[image: Newly affected]

Answering the other questions, I do grow in pots in my patio. They are all the same seeds and the variety on the packaging said "Tomate Roma".

[image: Pots]

A more detailed picture of the pots I use:
[image: Pot]

Pots are with a mix that always worked for me and was recommended by the store. I make them with some small rocks at the bottom to get the best drainage possible.

The plastic things around the plants inside the pots are just cylinders which get no more than 3 cm into the dirt to avoid ants and other insects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What impressed me most was the fruit seems to look fine from the outside and first inspection.

The closest I could come up with until we know more information, is Buckeye rot.  Even this usually shows some sign, symptoms on the fruit before cutting it open.

I am curious to what led you to suspect something was wrong with these tomatoes.  You have pictures of these tomatoes on the vine, off the vine and then you cut them open to show this rot that somehow you knew was there!  Somehow something prompted you to take pictures.  Or your tomatoes are beautifully regular and you've got very stable healthy plants!  And these aren't all the same tomatoes in all of the photos.  Are they?

That...mosquito thing...is not your problem, grins.

On the bottom of the one you cut open closest to us in the picture is a clear sign of rot that should have been apparent on the bottom before you cut it open.  Do you remember that?  This could be Bottom End Rot as well.  What is happening with the rest of the plant and the tomatoes left on your vine?  Where are you in this world?  Another picture would help.

Are your tomatoes grown in pots?  Out on the patio?  Are they in the garden? Do you remember the variety of tomato?

[Buckeye rot](http://www.aces.edu/pubs/docs/A/ANR-1054/ANR-1054.pdf)

Comment: Hello stormy, thank you very much for your answer. I have edited the post to reflect my answers and clarifications as requested.

Comment: Could be bottom end rot even Buckeye rot.  Are those ends soft?  Pots look great.  Not at all sure what the tubes are for as yet, irrigation?  Is this what you mean saying no more than 3cm into the soil is to counteract ants and insects?  Hummmm.  The pebbles at the bottom of your pots actually ruin drainage.  I know...but this is true.  They actually make a perched water table.  All the soil with the small pore spaces above the rocks with large pore spaces has to become saturated before any of the water will begin to drain into the rock.  Not good.  Use just soil.  Sterilized potting soil.

Comment: Is this rot in every tomato?  Did you say you used fertilizer, or not?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip on the rocks of the bottom of the pots. I haven't used any specific fertilizer. At the beginning I checked and most tomatoes were healthy but now it looks like only one or two remain clear of this. For the pictures I've seen on the internet I'm going to get calcium for *bottom end rot* as all of them start at the bottom and it looks more like that one. I think it's already too late so I will continue with my "practical lessons" :) .

Comment: I would go with just basic balanced fertilizer.  I trust Osmocote https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcium_deficiency_(plant_disorder), that is simple, straight forward and extended release 14-14-14.  Calcium deficiency is caused by many other problems.  I've never ADDED Ca to my potted plants, as long as basic needs are met, plants don't really need added chemistry.  Check this article maybe you've already read this...I do not see this as any thing other than a few fungus spores splashing up on the stem and leaves, bacteria inserted by a fly when the fruit was but a flower...